# Grid Layout: how to stretch an element (combobox) to the whole cell?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I create an simple grid, but cannot to stretch combobox element (State) to the whole cell (just as six element of grid (Group) ).

The code is:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;

}

#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows:  1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1vw;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
}


#grid > div {
  font-size: medium;
  padding: .5em;
  background: white;
  text-align: justify;
}

.auto-fill {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(150px, 1fr));
}

.auto-fit {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(150px, 1fr));
}



.box3 {
  align-self: stretch;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid" class ="grid auto-fill">
  <div>
    Version:
  </div>

  <div>
    <select (change)="changeVersion($event)" formControlName="version">
      <option value="" disabled>Select one or more elements of Versions</option>
      <option *ngFor="let state of Versions" [ngValue]="version">
        {{ state }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>State:</div>
  <div class="box3">
    <select (change)="changeState($event)" formControlName="state">
      <option value="" disabled>Select state of Work Item</option>
      <option *ngFor="let state of States" [ngValue]="state">
        {{ state }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Only open groups</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <form [formGroup]="inputForm">
      <input type="radio" formControlName="choice" value="True" /> True<br />
      <input type="radio" formControlName="choice" value="False" /> False<br />
    </form>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Groups</p>
  </div>
  <div >
    <select (change)="changeGroup($event)" formControlName="group">
      <option value="" disabled>
        Select Group (one or more)
      </option>
      <option *ngFor="let group of Groups" [ngValue]="group">
        {{ group }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>


  <div>
    <p>Some text</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <select (change)="changeSomething($event)" formControlName="something">
      <option value="" disabled>Select one or more rows</option>
      <option *ngFor="let line of Lines" [ngValue]="line">{{ line }}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Some text</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <form [formGroup]="inputForm">
      <input type="radio" formControlName="test" value="True" /> True<br />
      <input type="radio" formControlName="test" value="False" /> False<br />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my case it looks like:

[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you probably need to set a width to the select element. (if not clarify ;) )

`select {width:100%;}`

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
}

#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1vw;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
}

#grid>div {
  font-size: medium;
  padding: .5em;
  background: white;
  text-align: justify;
}

.auto-fill {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(150px, 1fr));
}

.auto-fit {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(150px, 1fr));
}

.box3 {
  align-self: stretch;
}

select {
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div id="grid" class="grid auto-fill">
  <div>
    Version:
  </div>

  <div>
    <select (change)="changeVersion($event)" formControlName="version">
      <option value="" disabled>Select one or more elements of Versions</option>
      <option *ngFor="let state of Versions" [ngValue]="version">
        {{ state }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>State:</div>
  <div class="box3">
    <select (change)="changeState($event)" formControlName="state">
      <option value="" disabled>Select state of Work Item</option>
      <option *ngFor="let state of States" [ngValue]="state">
        {{ state }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Only open groups</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <form [formGroup]="inputForm">
      <input type="radio" formControlName="choice" value="True" id="tr1" name="oop" /> True<br />
      <input type="radio" formControlName="choice" value="False" id="fs1" name="oop" /> False<br />
    </form>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Groups</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <select (change)="changeGroup($event)" formControlName="group">
      <option value="" disabled>
        Select Group (one or more)
      </option>
      <option *ngFor="let group of Groups" [ngValue]="group">
        {{ group }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>


  <div>
    <p>Some text</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <select (change)="changeSomething($event)" formControlName="something">
      <option value="" disabled>Select one or more rows</option>
      <option *ngFor="let line of Lines" [ngValue]="line">{{ line }}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Some text</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <form [formGroup]="inputForm">
      <input type="radio" formControlName="test" value="True" id="tr2" name="st"/> True<br />
      <input type="radio" formControlName="test" value="False" id="fs2" name="oop"/> False<br />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```